# Allow integers from 0 to 59 after ':' in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to enter after `:` a value from `0` to `59` max. For example:

```
350:59
20:22
```

This code works but max after `:` is `99`

```
$("#duration").on('input', function() { 
  this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\:?\d{0,2}/); 
});
```

Comment: this code works but max after ":" is 99



$( "#duration" ).on('input', function () {
                    this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\:?\d{0,2}/);
                });

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question, using the `edit` button if you need to add details later, if you forgot. I've done it for you in this case

Comment: `\:?\d{0,2}` -> `(?::[0-5]\d)?` or - to allow live validation, ``(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?``

Comment: I want to enter numbers but after ":" I want to enter only two numbers going from 0 to 59